# Show that $||f||_{\infty} \leqslant \alpha \iff |f|\leqslant \alpha \text{ a.e}.$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ a measure space and
$f :X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function.  Show that for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^+,$
$$||f||_{\infty} \leqslant \alpha \iff |f|\leqslant \alpha \text{  a.e}.$$
My attempt : $\Leftarrow)$ Evident.

$\Rightarrow)$ Let $\alpha \geqslant 0. $ For all $n\geqslant 1,$ $\exists \;\beta_n$ : $||f||_{\infty} \leqslant \beta_n < ||f||_{\infty}+\dfrac{1}{n} \leqslant \alpha+\dfrac{1}{n}.$

$||f||_{\infty} \leqslant \beta_n \implies \color{red}{|f| \leqslant \beta_n }$ a.e (by definiton of $||.||_{\infty})$.

$\beta_n < \alpha+\dfrac{1}{n} \implies$ $\color{red}{\{ |f| > \beta_n\} \supset \{ |f| > \alpha+\frac{1}{n}\}}$, or
$\displaystyle\{ |f| > \alpha\}=\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1} \left\{ |f|> \alpha+\frac{1}{n}\right\}$,

therefore $ \mu (\left\{ |f|> \alpha\right\})=0.$ i.e $|f|\leqslant \alpha \text{ a.e}.$

Questions : is that correct ? why do we call $||f||_{\infty}$ the $\color{red}{\text{essential}}$ supremum of $f$ ?

Comment: Your argument looks circular. In the second line of $\implies $) aren't you already assuming what you have to prove?

Comment: I didn't exactly know where's the problem, so if you can please elaborate? In fact, i didn't understand well $||.||_{\infty}$ !

Comment: You said that $\|f\|_{\infty} \leq \beta_n$ implies $|f| \leq \beta_n$ a.e. ('by definition of $\|f\|_{\infty}$'). But this is what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Yes you are right ! so how can i correct it ?

Comment: I think , i should try to understand well what this norm means,
So please  can you give me some references (books, lectures, websites, ... ,anything) which can helps me to understand well and trying to answer it myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the definition you are using is $\|f\|_{\infty} =\inf \{t>0: \mu (|f|>t)=0\}$.
Let us prove the contrapositive of the implication ($\implies$ part). Suppose $\mu (|f| >\alpha ) >0$. Then $\mu (|f| >\alpha +\frac 1 n ) >0$ for some $n$ . This is because $ (|f| >\alpha +\frac 1 n )$ increase to $ (|f| >\alpha )$. Now $\beta <\alpha +\frac 1 n$ implies $\mu (|f| >\beta)>0$. Hence $\{t: \mu (|f| >t)=0\}$ is contained in $[\alpha+\frac 1 n, \infty)$ and the infimum of $\{t: \mu (|f| >t)=0\}$ is greater than or equal to $\alpha+\frac 1 n$. In other words $\|f\|_{\infty} \geq \alpha+\frac 1 n >\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you so much !